# Asynchronous javascript and google map

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I am building a wordpress website and I am trying to optimize it for speed (I'm a total newbie). According to the Google page speed insight tool, I need to use aysynchronous javascript to eliminate render-blocking JavaScript. I have looked around and I have found the asynchronous javascript plugin the problem is that it prevents my google map from loading.

Here is what this plugin did to the javascripts files of my homepage:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    head.js({
        "comment-reply": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.3"
    }, {
        "address": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.address-1.5.min.js"
    }, {
        "triple-layout": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/triple.layout.js"
    }, {
        "smoothscroll": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/smoothscroll.js"
    }, {
        "nprogress": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/nprogress/nprogress.js"
    }, {
        "fastclick": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/fastclick.js"
    }, {
        "imagesloaded": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"
    }, {
        "isotope": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"
    }, {
        "flexslider": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"
    }, {
        "fitvids": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.fitvids.js"
    }, {
        "validate": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.validate.min.js"
    }, {
        "uniform": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.uniform.min.js"
    }, {
        "fancybox": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"
    }, {
        "tooltipster": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"
    }, {
        "prettify": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"
    }, {
        "twitter-fetcher": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/twitterFetcher_v10_min.js"
    }, {
        "mediaelement-and-player": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"
    }, {
        "send-mail": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/send-mail.js"
    }, {
        "classie": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/classie.js"
    }, {
        "google-maps-api": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"
    }, {
        "main": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/main.js"
    }, {
        "wp-fix": "http://http://localhost:8888//wp-content/themes/customtheme/js/wp-fix.js"
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking it! The 'async' attribute of the `<script>` tag means that the browser render engine will continue parsing the page for display while still running the Javascript in parallel. This is a good thing, unless you have some compelling reason for the browser to up sticks and halt while the `<script>` is executed before proceeding to the markup following it. It ensures pages render snappily.

So instead of

```
<script src="myJS.js"></script>
```

you use

```
<script src="myJS.js" async></script>
```

I suspect your 'asynchronous JS plugin' that you found may be for some other purpose entirely?

I would, however, ensure that your code that sets up and interacts with teh Google map(s) on your page is executed once the DOM is ready (e.g. inside a jQuery `$(function() { /* set up map here */ });`)